# Write ARIMA model from auto.arima output

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I want to write down the mathematical model for the following `arima.test` output:

```
> auto.arima(x)
Series: x 
ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0)[12] with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1    sar1       mean
      0.4706  0.5623  6304.4752
s.e.  0.1332  0.1262   828.9899

sigma^2 estimated as 3550092:  log likelihood=-538.48
AIC=1084.96   AICc=1085.68   BIC=1093.33
```

I understand this is a seasonal model with period 12, and *p*, *d*, and *q* are respectively 1, 0, and 0, for both the series and the seasonal parts.

However, I fail to interpretate the meaning of the coefficients and how to write this model together, what kind of formula I need to apply.

Comment: Note that there have been many similar questions of which this is quite certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link explains non-seasonal ARIMA](https://otexts.org/fpp2/arima-r.html), and [this link explains seasonal ARIMA](https://otexts.org/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html) in R. (Note that other software packages have different conventions, in particular in terms of intercepts and of the sign for MA components.) Putting everything together, your ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0)[12] model is, using the backshift operator $B$:

$$ (1-\phi_1B)(1-\Phi_1B^{12})y_t = c+\epsilon_t, $$

or

$$ (1-\phi_1B)(y_t-\Phi_1y_{t-12}) = c+\epsilon_t, $$

or

$$ y_t-\phi_1y_{t-1}-\Phi_1y_{t-12}+\phi_1\Phi_1y_{t-13} = c+\epsilon_t, $$

where your parameter estimates are

$$ \hat{\phi}_1=0.4706, \quad\hat{\Phi}_1=0.5623,\quad \hat{c}=6304.4752,\quad \epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)\text{ with }\hat{\sigma}^2=3550092.$$